# error System.Threading.Tasks.Task when returning from an async function

Tags: c#, node.js, electron

I am using a package named `electron-cgi` to communicate between electron js and c#. The connection is established properly and I can send data between the two. The problem is when I await the data I want to send to Electron I get error `` One or more errors occurred. (Serialisation failed for: { Type = RESPONSE, Response = ElectronCgi.DotNet.Response`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]] }.) ``. Why is this error occurring? I am awaiting the response from the post request I made so `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` shouldn't be occurring. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Documentation for the electron-cgi library: https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/electron-cgi

**C#**

```
using ElectronCgi.DotNet;

static void Main(string[] args) {

  var connection = new ConnectionBuilder()
    .WithLogging()
    .Build();

  static async Task < string > getCred(string testing) {
    using
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var jsonString = "{\"requestType\": \"" + testing + "\"}";
    var data = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var url = "http://serverIp:port/api/server";

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    dynamic parsedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

    string cred = parsedResult.cred;

    var credArrVec = cred.Split('\n');

    return credArrVec;
  }


  connection.On("getCred", async(string testing) => {
    //error occurs here
    var test = await getCred(testing);
    return test;
  });
  
  connection.Listen();

}
```

**NodeJs**

```js
const {
  ConnectionBuilder
} = require("electron-cgi");

const connection = new ConnectionBuilder()
  .connectTo("dotnet", "run", "--project", "../testProject")
  .build();

connection.onDisconnect = () => {
  console.log("Connection between node and .net lost");
};

connection.send("getCred", "testCred", (error, res) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error); //serialized exception from the .NET handler
    return;
  }

  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure but aren't you returning an array when using `Split` method ? Your return method type should be Task<string[]> ? In fact I do not understand how this is compiling ^^